# Display troubles with canvas

Tags: java, graphics, awt

Currently I am trying to have a `JFrame` which holds two `JPanel` components - the first `JPanel` component is meant to hold the various buttons that a user can click to interact with the program & draw images to the screen. The second, and this is where the trouble begins, holds the actual `Canvas` object to which I am trying to draw to.

The problem I am having is the second panel is not actually being drawn to. I've tried a variety of other approaches and checks, but everything suggests the current code *should* work.

As a test, I am simply trying to do a `fillRect()` onto the drawing panel, but to no avail. Here is my code:

//Creating the components & JFrame:

```
    public static void createDisplay() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();//When JFrame flowlayout manager removed, the rectangle was drawn.
        c = new Canvas();

        width = 500;
        height = 500;

        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        f.add(addButtons()); //private method that covers the button panel

        JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();


        drawPanel.add(c);

        c.setFocusable(false);

        f.add(drawPanel);

        f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(height, width));

        lstnr = new Listeners();

        f.addKeyListener(lstnr);
        f.addMouseListener(lstnr);
        f.addMouseMotionListener(lstnr);

        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);


}
```

And the code that does the actual drawing to the screen:

```
private void render() {

    bs = c.getBufferStrategy();

    if(bs == null) {
        c.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }


    do {
        do {
            g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            l.setGraphicsObj(g);
            g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

            for(Symbols s : l.getSymbolsArray());

                s.renderSymbols();
            }
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50); //Just to test & make sure it works

            g.dispose();

        }while(bs.contentsRestored());

        bs.show();
    }while(bs.contentsLost());

}
```

Now I'd like to stress again that the rectangle *was drawn* when I removed the `f.setLayoutManager(new FlowLayout());` snippet from the `createDisplay()` method. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, first up, it would be, very, very difficult to get a actively painting `Canvas` to work nicely with Swing. Second, heavy weight components, like `Canvas`, don't tend to play well when contained within Swing components - I know, it's "suppose" to be fixed, but I've seen a solution which actually works all the time.  Thirdly, the `Canvas` doesn't have a default size, so `FlowLayout` will default it to `0x0`

Comment: Thanks for the help @MadProgrammer. The canvas being set to 0x0 was my primary issue. However, is there a better way to do what I am trying to do? I’d like to have this look better than something out of the 90’s

Comment: Since I have 0 context of what you're trying to achieve, it's impossible to make further suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have conflicting painting systems.  The one been used to paint the `BufferStrategy` and the one been used by Swing to paint it's components
2. Mixing heavy and light weight components is problematic at the best of times, you should do everything you can to reduce the overlap
3. A `Canvas` has a default preferred size of `0x0`, which is what the `FlowLayout` will use to determine how best it should be laid out

A "possible" solution might be to focus on placing the `Canvas` within it's own spot and seperate the Swing elements.

You're still running into a world of trouble, as you will need to manage the data between two distinct thread contexts

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                PaintPane paintPane = new PaintPane();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new ButtonPane(), BorderLayout.WEST);
                frame.add(paintPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                paintPane.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class ButtonPane extends JPanel {

        public ButtonPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            for (int index =0; index < 5; index++) {
                add(new JButton(Integer.toString(index)), gbc);
            }
        }

    }

    public class PaintPane extends Canvas {

        private Thread renderThread;
        private AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(true);

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        public void start() {
            if (renderThread != null) {
                return;
            }

            running.set(true);
            renderThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (running.get()) {
                        render();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            renderThread.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (renderThread != null) {
                return;
            }
            running.set(false);
            renderThread.interrupt();
            try {
                renderThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            renderThread = null;
        }

        protected void render() {
            BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

            if (bs == null) {
                createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;
            }

            do {
                do {
                    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
                    // :/
                    //l.setGraphicsObj(g);
                    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

                    //for (Symbols s : l.getSymbolsArray()) {
                    //  // This is where g should be passed
                    //  s.renderSymbols();
                    //}
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50); //Just to test & make sure it works
                    g.dispose();
                } while (bs.contentsRestored());
                bs.show();
            } while (bs.contentsLost());
        }

    }

}
```